# Thread dump with .net 4

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-4.0

Good day.
I'm trying to get a thread dump (stack trace and state for each running thread) in a .net 4 framework application.

Managed Stack Explorer doesn't do the trick for .net 4 I presume (I can't really find info on it), it shows only .net 3.5 and down applications.

Process explorer does give a thread dump, but with start addresses rather then stack trace which isn't very helpful.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this a running app or one in your IDE?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you on Vista or Windows7?

Are you on 32 or 64bit?

Right click the process in Task Manager and select 'Create Dump File'. You can then drag the DMP file into Visual Studio (as long as its a .NET4 process) and view the information you require. see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5zhxt22.aspx) for more information.

*shameless plug* See also [my post](http://wallaceturner.com/debugging-dump-files-created-on-another-machine) on all the issues you might encounter obtaining and analyzing a dump file

Comment: I've created a dump file, but VS2010 pro cannot attach it to my PDBs for a reason, all I get is a cryptic start addresses for dlls. Nor can it find my sources.

Comment: was the dump taken on a 64bit machine and is the machine you are debugging on 64bit? 
Do your pdb's match with your running app? (this is most likely your problem)

Comment: @wal: dump were taken on 32 bit machine. What do you mean by "pdb matching my app?" I took the pdbs from the build output dir (the same dir which I took the exe and dlls to run my app). Is it ok?

Comment: Start debugging your dump file then open the modules window. (Debug->Windows->Modules). Search for your user-code module and see if the Symbol File is being loaded. Attempt to load the pdb from the *original* path. I just made a dump file of a simple one line Forms app and there is alot of unmanaged code in the dump. Do you see any managed stack frames in Parallel Stacks (Debug->Windows->Parallel Stacks)

Comment: put your pdb's in the same folder as your dump file.

Comment: @wal: I did as you've instructed. and indeed, my exe (TradingEngine.exe) doesn't have its PDB loaded. trying to load the PDB manually result in error "a matching symbol file was not found in this folder". Now, I am SURE this is the PDB from the last build I did!

Comment: @wal: Also, in the Symbol Status column, it states "No native symbols in symbol file"

Comment: I've opened the dump from visual studio where I have the solution opened. this seems to have done the trick. I can see my calls now. still no source code, but it's parsecs from where I was. Thanks mates.

Comment: yes i noticed that error too when i tried it. it seems to have some issue there hence saying put pdb's into dump folder or visa versa. since u are new to SO i shld tell you to accept my answer if you are now happy. :)